# Why And When Do You Need to Update Your SQLite Database Version In Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a simple application that uses a database derived from `db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(...)`. Now, when I create it I use `db.setVersion(1);`

And I read somewhere that I have to change the database version each time I change it. Now I can't find the particular tutorial where I read this, so I am left with some questions.

1)What is the reason behind versioning of a database? What is a practical purpose?

2)When exactly should the version be updated? After every insert? Every additional table added?

3)Will I be in trouble if I don't update the versions after `1`? What would it lead to?

Answer (score 0):

1)Versioning the database is really versioning your schema.  This allows you to know when the schema is changed so you can convert it.

2)Whenever you change the schema.

3)If you change the schema, you won't know which one is being used and will end up with exceptions.  If you never change the schema, nothing will happen.

And you shouldn't be manually calling setVersion.  It already knows the version for an existing one, and you pass in the version elsewhere if its a new database.

Answer (score 0):

The *SQLite Database Version In Android* is only neccessary if you manage database creation and version updates with the **[SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)**.

`SQLiteOpenHelper` takes care of

- opening the database if it exists,
- creating it if it does not exis,
- upgrading its schema if necessary
- sets the SQLite Database Version.

The databaseverionnumber is set in the SQLiteDatabase-constructor.

Your example `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(...)` does not use `SQLiteOpenHelper` so in this case there is no need set the dbversion.